# Magento2: How to show .phtml file in a popup

Tags: modal-dialog, magento2

I need to open the data from a .phtml file (gallery.phtml) in a modal popup in Magento2. This is the code used to include modal scripts:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" id="click-me">Click Me</a>
</div>


<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                content: 'gallery.phtml',
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-mpdal'));
            $("#click-me").on('click',function(){
                $("#popup-mpdal").modal("openModal");
            });

        }
    );
</script>
```

The gallery.phtml file is given below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="popup-mpdal">
    <h1> Hi I'm here.... </h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

But the popup is not coming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the answer:

```
<div>
    <a href="#" id="click-me">Click Me</a>
</div>

<div id="popup-mpdal" >
    <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Vendor_Module::gallery.phtml')) ?>
</div>

<script>
    require(
        [
            'jquery',
            'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
        ],
        function(
            $,
            modal
        ) {
            var options = {
                type: 'popup',
                responsive: true,
                innerScroll: true,
                buttons: [{
                    text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                    class: '',
                    click: function () {
                        this.closeModal();
                    }
                }]
            };

            var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-mpdal'));
            $("#click-me").on('click',function(){
                $("#popup-mpdal").modal("openModal");
            });

        }
    );
</script>
```

Comment: Should I use multiple links on the same page for the popup?

Comment: I used this to display Add review form in popup. Added the code in list.phtml where I have "Rate" button. I included the phtml file like this : <?php include ($block->getTemplateFile('Magento_Review::form.phtml')) ?> Here the Block class Form.php is not mentioned. So the Form.php block class is not accessible. Any solution?

Comment: ok.. Got the solution. I used this code: <div id="popup-mpdal" >
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Review\Block\Form")->setTemplate("Magento_Review::form.phtml")->toHtml(); ?>
</div>

Answer (score 3):

I have used this in html

```
    <button type="button" class="action" data-trigger="trigger">
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Click Here'"></span>
</button>
<div data-bind="mageInit: {
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal':{
            'type': 'popup',
            'title': 'Popup title',
            'trigger': '[data-trigger=trigger]',
            'responsive': true,
            'buttons': [{
                text: 'Submit',
                class: 'action'
            }]
        }}">
    <div class="content">
        Popup Content
    </div>
</div>
```